# Add border to UITextField

Tags: ios, swift

I want to add border to my UITextField like the this image

[image]

so I used this code

```
    let rectShape = CAShapeLayer()
    rectShape.bounds = self.userNameText.frame
    rectShape.position = self.userNameText.center


    rectShape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.userNameText.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [ UIRectCorner.TopLeft , UIRectCorner.BottomRight ], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 5.0 , height: 5.0)).CGPath

    self.userNameText.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
    //Here I'm masking the textView's layer with rectShape layer
    self.userNameText.layer.mask = rectShape
```

but the result was like this

[image]

Did I miss something ??

Comment: "did I miss something" Obviously yes. Did you have a real question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give the text field no border, and set its `background` however you like.

[image]

```
self.textField.borderStyle = .None
let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.textField.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [ UIRectCorner.TopLeft , UIRectCorner.BottomRight ], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 8.0 , height: 8.0))
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.textField.bounds.size, false, 0)
path.stroke()
self.textField.background = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the code from

```
rectShape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.userNameText.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [ UIRectCorner.TopLeft , UIRectCorner.BottomRight ], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 5.0 , height: 5.0)).CGPath
```

to

```
rectShape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.userNameText.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [ UIRectCorner.BottomRight ,  UIRectCorner.TopLeft  ], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 5.0 , height: 5.0)).CGPath
```

and see if the bottom right corner rounds properly like the top left one is now and if the top left looks like the bottom right one is now. It's weird the all of the corners are rounding out like that except for the top left one.

**A Recommendation:** Try out [textFieldEffects](https://github.com/raulriera/TextFieldEffects). It's a really cool open source project that allows you to create modern, visually appealing text fields in storyboard without any code! I just implemented it in my app and it looks great! The only complaint I have is that I can't get the didBeginEditing and didEndEditing functions to work (maybe a problem on my end).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to get pretty close to what you are looking for:

```
let rectShape = CAShapeLayer()
rectShape.bounds = self.userNameText.frame
rectShape.position = self.userNameText.center

rectShape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.usernameTextField.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [ UIRectCorner.TopLeft , UIRectCorner.BottomRight ], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 5.0 , height: 5.0)).CGPath

rectShape.fillColor = nil
rectShape.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor

self.userNameText.layer.addSublayer(rectShape)
self.userNameText.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None
```

Here we turned off the border on the UITextField and added the shape as a sublayer.

Answer (score 0):

My code will help you:

```
UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.viewTable.bounds
                                                           byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerBottomRight | UIRectCornerTopLeft
                                                                 cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(13.0, 13.0)];

   // Create the shape layer and set its path
 CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
 maskLayer.frame = txtFiled.bounds;
 maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
 maskLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor orangeColor].CGColor;
 txtFiled.layer.mask = maskLayer;

 CAShapeLayer *shape = [CAShapeLayer layer];
 shape.frame = txtFiled.bounds;
 shape.path = maskPath.CGPath;
 shape.lineWidth = 1.0f;
 shape.strokeColor = [UIColor orangeColor].CGColor;
 shape.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
 [txtFiled.layer insertSublayer:shape above:maskLayer];
 txtFiled.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
 txtFiled.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
 txtFiled.layer.rasterizationScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
```